# translate 2 div's using google api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-translate

I have a web site where in it is required to translate website from english to Arabic. Web site is done in .net and some constant data are being translated using resource file. Where as dynamic data which is coming from database needs to be translated using google api. using the code [here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started) I can translate a perticular div. How to translate more than 1 different div's on same page.On one page data needs to be translated using google api as well as resource file

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow for Google Translate api

[Google Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889438/how-to-enable-google-transliteration-for-multiple-dynamic-textboxes-asp-net)

Sample Google Translate using JS

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html> 
     <head> 
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
     <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">   </script>  
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;"> 

<div id="google_translate_element">
<input type="text" id="txtDetails" />
</div>

</body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Google Transliterate API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                destinationLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.KANNADA,
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled: true
            };

            // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
            // options.
            var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

            // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
            // 'transliterateTextarea'.
            control.makeTransliteratable(['txtDetails']);
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
</html>
```

Or Microsoft Translator using bellow

[Microsoft Translate](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hec.ravi/create-language-translator-using-Asp-Net/)

Comment: Can I implement above translate using google translate api ? because I have an goole api key

Comment: Yes you need to load JS reference with this given key. you can get further reference @ https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/reference#ref  Pls mark the question as answer if it helps you

Comment: can i get the sample code pls because I'm confused as in where and how to use google api key after reading documentation